# Find angle $ \angle AED $ in the following triangle.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

Find  angle $ \angle AED  $ in the following triangle.[image]

In the above triangle we have : $CA=CB ,CE=DB=BA ,\angle ACB =20^° , \angle CAB=\angle CBA=80^°$ now find $ \angle AED  $.

I think if we draw line $AD$ we have $AB=BD$ then $\angle BAD= \angle BDA =50^°$ then in the triangle $ AED$ we have $\angle EAD=30^°$ but I can't find $ \angle AED  $

Answer (score 0):

Clathratus, how did you prove that AEDB is cyclic since you have used the external angle theorem of a cyclic quadrilateral when you say that angle CED is equal to angle DBA ?